# Not getting error but data was not stored in database in laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-8

Hello everyone i'm actually stuck for hours because of this, im new to laravel and idk whats wrong with my code and there is no actual message error, please help me

This my store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'jenis_id' => 'required',
        'detjenis_id' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
    ]);
    $asep = $request->name;
    dd($asep);
    $order = new DataOrder();
    $order->name = $request->name;
    $order->jenis_id = $request->jenis_id;
    $order->detjenis_id = $request->detjenis_id;
    $order->email = $request->number;
    $order->message = $request->message;
    $order->save();
    //return back()->with('alert-success', '<script> window.onload = swal("Sukses!", "Data telah terkirim!", "success")</script>');
    // if ($order->save()) {
    //     return redirect(route('home'))->with('alert-success', '<script> window.onload = swal("Sukses!", "Data telah terkirim!", "success")</script>');
    // } else {
    //     return redirect(route('home'))->with('alert-success', '<script> window.onload = swal("Oops !" ,  "Data gagal terkirim!!" ,  "error")</script>');
    // }
}
```

This my blade code

```
<form action="{{route('order.store')}}" method="POST">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="tm-section-wrap bg-white">
    <section id="talk" class="row tm-section">
        <div class="col-xl-6 mb-5">
            <div class="tm-contact-form-wrap">
                <div class="tm-contact-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"
                            class="form-control rounded-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0"
                            placeholder="Nama anda..." required="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Kebutuhan</label>
                        <select name="jenis_id" class="form-control" id="jenis_id">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih dibawah ini:</option>
                            @foreach ($jenis as $j)
                            <option value="{{$j->id}}">{{$j->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Detail</label>
                        <select name="detjenis_id" class="form-control" id="detjenis_id">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" id="number" name="number"
                            class="form-control rounded-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0"
                            placeholder="Nomor HP" required="" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea rows="4" id="message" name="message"
                            class="form-control rounded-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0"
                            placeholder="Message..." required=""></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mb-0">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn rounded-0 d-block ml-auto tm-btn-primary">
                            SEND
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

and my route setup

```
Route::get('/testcrud', 'HomeController@testcrud')->name('testcrud');
Route::resource('SAS/order', 'DataOrderController');
```

Thank you if there anyone can help me with this problem, i'm really appreciate that.

Comment: This line looks sus: `$order->email = $request->number;`.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, There is `email` field is missing in your form and you are using :

```
'email' => 'required'
```

Thats why data is not saving in database. For displaying validation error you can [check here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you already put all the field name,jenis_id,detjenis_id,email,message
in the fillable array in the model?
or if you don't want to bother doing that? you can just create a empty
protected $guarded variable on model.

And are you sure about the field? because i see you put number on email field.

Comment: He is not doing a [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment), there is no need to add those fields into the `fillable` array.